# Count number of Strings and JSONObjects in JSONArray

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to parse a JSON schema and I need to get all the image links from the JSONArray and store it in a java array. The JSONArray looks like this:

[image]

How can I get only the number of strings in the image array for e.g. In this case it should be 4? I know how to get the full length of array but how can I only get the number of strings?

**UPDATE:**

I am simply parsing it using the standard JSON parser for android. The length of JSONArray can be calculated using:

```
JSONArray imageArray = hist.getJSONArray("image");
int len = imageArray.length();
```

`len` will be equal to 9 in this case.

Comment: What JSON parser are you using?  Can you clarify what you mean when you say `I know how to get the full length of array but how can I only get the number of strings`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a better way (there probably is), but here's one option:

According to [the Android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#getJSONObject(int)), `getJSONObject` will throw a `JSONException` if the element at the specified index is not a JSON object.  So, you can try to get the element at each index using `getJSONObject`.  If it throws a `JSONException`, then you know it's not a JSON object.  You can then try and get the element using `getString`.  Here's a crude example:

```
JSONArray imageArray = hist.getJSONArray("image");
int len = imageArray.length();
ArrayList<String> imageLinks = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    boolean isObject = false;
    try {
        JSONArray obj = imageArray.getJSONObject(i);
        // obj is a JSON object
        isObject = true;
    } catch (JSONException ex) {
        // ignore
    }
    if (!isObject ) {
        // Element at index i was not a JSON object, might be a String
        try {
            String strVal = imageArray.getString(i);
            imageLinks.add(strVal);
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            // ignore
        }
    }
}
int numImageLinks = imageLinks.size();
```

Comment: You interpreted it wrong, there is no subArray. There is only 1 array image which contains few strings and few JSONObjects. I can get total number of elements in a JSONArray using imageArray.length(); but if I had to get only the number of strings then how can I get that number?